# How can you wait for a function to run all its code includingh animation before other computing function can take place? JavaScript and JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'am trying to make a rock paper scissor game on the web.

Everything works just that I want the animation of the two hands going up and down 3 times before changing the pictures to the correct values.

But instead it keeps ongoing and executes the next code for the button input.

```
$(".adjust-button").click(function(){
            const npc = getNpcChoice(3);
            const player = $(this).val();
            animateShake().promise().done(checkResults);
        });

        function animateShake(){
            let timer = $.Deferred();
            $("img").animate({paddingTop: "0px", paddingBottom: "100px"},300);
            $("img").animate({paddingTop: "50px", paddingBottom: "50px"},300);
            $("img").animate({paddingTop: "0px", paddingBottom: "100px"},300);
            $("img").animate({paddingTop: "50px", paddingBottom: "50px"},300);
            $("img").animate({paddingTop: "0px", paddingBottom: "100px"},300);
            $("img").animate({paddingTop: "50px", paddingBottom: "50px"},300);
            
            return timer.resolve();
        }

        function checkResults(playe, np){
           // $leftSign.attr("src", (`/images/${player}-from-left.png`));
           // $rightSign.attr("src", (`/images/${npc}-from-right.png`));

            $leftSign.attr("src", (`/images/rock-from-left.png`));
            $rightSign.attr("src", (`/images/paper-from-right.png`));
            let player = "rock";
            let npc = "paper";
        }
```

I want the method animateShake() to completely run all its animations before the next method checkResults(playe, np) runs.

I have for the sake of testing changed the parameters for this last function and just check if the pictures changes before the animation which they do...

I also need to be able to pass arguments to this last method.

I have tried the method resolve and done but can't get this to work they way I want to.

Iam using jQuery for this.

Comment: You will want to learn about [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to solve that. Then return a promise from your function that resolves whenever the things you want to be done have finished.

Answer (score 0):

As you're performing the `animate()` call on the same element you can simply return that from the `animateShake()` function and use the `promise()` it returns to call `checkResults()` when the promise is resolved after the queued animations complete. Try this:

```js
$(".adjust-button").click(function() {
  animateShake().promise().done(checkResults);
});

function animateShake() {
  return $("img") 
    .animate({ paddingTop: "0px", paddingBottom: "100px" }, 300)
    .animate({ paddingTop: "50px", paddingBottom: "50px" }, 300)
    .animate({ paddingTop: "0px", paddingBottom: "100px" }, 300)
    .animate({ paddingTop: "50px", paddingBottom: "50px" }, 300)
    .animate({ paddingTop: "0px", paddingBottom: "100px" }, 300)
    .animate({ paddingTop: "50px", paddingBottom: "50px" }, 300);
}

function checkResults() {
  console.log('all done');
}
```

```css
img {   
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="adjust-button">Adjust</button>
<img />
```

Comment: How can i go about to also pass on arguments to the checkResults funtion?